# html helper issue with DateTimeFormatInfo() and FirstDayOfWeek

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've got a little issue that's bugging me today!! I've created a little helper method that I want to ALWAYS return monday as the 1st day of week (i.e. monday=0) but can't seem to figure out where i'm going wrong. I'm setting what I 'feel' is an override of the prevailing culture but to no avail.

Without further ado, the code:

```
public static string ComboDaysOfWeekNumber(this HtmlHelper helper, 
                     string id, string selectedValue)
{
    var cultureInfo = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
    cultureInfo.FirstDayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Monday;
    var newitems = cultureInfo
        .DayNames
        .Select((dayName, index) => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value =(index).ToString(),
            Text = dayName,
            Selected = (selectedValue == dayName)
        });

    var result = helper.DropDownList(id, newitems).ToHtmlString();
    return result;
}
```

usage:

```
<%=Html.ComboDaysOfWeekNumber("weekSplitEnd", myModelDayNo.ToString())%>
```

No matter what, this is ALWAYS starting on sunday=0.

any thoughts out there??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DayNames` is not dependent on the `FirstDayOfWeek` property and setting it won't have any effect. You could try this instead:

```
var cultureInfo = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
var dayNames = new[] 
{
    DayOfWeek.Monday, DayOfWeek.Tuesday, DayOfWeek.Wednesday, 
    DayOfWeek.Thursday, DayOfWeek.Friday, DayOfWeek.Saturday, 
    DayOfWeek.Sunday 
}.Select(cultureInfo.GetDayName);

var newitems = dayNames
    .Select((dayName, index) => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value =(index).ToString(),
        Text = dayName,
        Selected = (selectedValue == dayName)
    });

var result = helper.DropDownList(id, newitems).ToHtmlString();
return result;
```

Comment: thanks darin, looks promising. causes an error unfortunately when run (mvc2). rushing out now, but will figure out the issue later. thanks again for the msg tho ;)

Comment: darin, will update as answer in a bit. just a quickie. can you think of a more 'generic' way of doing this, whereby the 1st dayofweek could be ANY day (i.e. a tuesday, a thursday etc)??

Answer (score 0):

Darin,

back now, here's what I came up woth:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ComboDaysOfWeekNumber(this HtmlHelper helper, 
                              string id, int selectedValue)
{

    var dayNames = new[]
                       {
                           DayOfWeek.Monday, DayOfWeek.Tuesday, 
                           DayOfWeek.Wednesday, DayOfWeek.Thursday, 
                           DayOfWeek.Friday, DayOfWeek.Saturday,
                           DayOfWeek.Sunday
                       };

    var newitems = dayNames
        .Select((dayName, index) => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value =(index).ToString(),
            Text = dayName.ToString(),
            Selected = (selectedValue == index)
        });

    var result = helper.DropDownList(id, newitems);
    return result;
}
```

this 'seems' to work as expected. thanks for the pointers.

jim